# Rails4 render by css id in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form produced by simple_form gem. All works fine.
This is the html of my form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/contacts" class="simple_form new_contact" id="new_contact" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

If I type in the browser `http://localhost:3000/contacts#new_contact` everything works fine: I'm redirect to the form in the bottom of page.

Is possible render the link `http://localhost:3000/contacts#new_contact` in the controller with the `render` method?
Something like this:

```
#contacts_controller.rb
render 'contacts#new_contact'
```

**EDIT**

Rendering the Contacts `index` page with the following link:

```
  <%= navbar_item "Contact", contacts_path %>
```

Comment: How are you going to render the `contacts` index page? As in what triggers it? Do you click on some link? Share the relevant code.

Comment: The contacts index page is a form to send an email. Sending the message is handled by the create action. The form is in the bottom of page. If there are errors in form I want to display the bottom of the page using this link `http://localhost:3000/contacts#new_contact` where `new_contact` is the form ID.

Comment: Thats fine. BUT how do you reach this `contacts index page` in the first place that is what I am asking?

Comment: The link of the index contact page is http://localhost:3000/contacts and is managed by the new action.

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Contacts form on *Contacts index page* as:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, url: contacts_path(anchor: 'new_contact') ,defaults: { label: false} do |f| %>
```

Pass the `url` option along with `anchor` in the `form` .